# Can't Select Database WordPress localhost setup

Tags: php, wordpress

I have no very little experience with coding in general and no relevant experience with WordPress. This is my first attempt to set up a WordPress site. I am using Wamp server on Windows 10 and I followed a beginner tutorial on how to set up a local WordPress site.

I have set up a Wamp server and have WordPress setup running on my localhost. I get the error Can't select database when attempting to set up. The name of my database in MySQL has no spaces in it and it SEEMS that the database has privileges set for the default user of root, it says "ALL PRIVILEGES"  I did some research and I think it is setting a config file to "**localhost:3308**" instead of "**localhost**" the posting describes users changing various elements of PHP files. to edit the database connection details "**wp-admin_setup-config.php_step=1**", another user changed the database host setting on the setup page, which I assume has something to do with Wamp Server.

WordPress Forum
[Can't select database error](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-select-database-wamp/).

I looked in the WordPress directories for several of the PHP setting files that they recommended in various forums and stack overflow discussions, And I don't know where to add this.

Thanks

Comment: create a database using mysql console or phpmyadmin.then try again with that db name

Comment: Okay, so I tried that and it still resulted in the same thing. I have been using the PHPMyAdmin to edit databases.  
[apache: 2.4.41]    [php: 7.3.12]   [mySql: 8.0.18 set to port 3308]  [wamp: 3.2.0 x64] should I create the db, restart the wamp server and then try to log in to WordPress?